# VBA Excel Calculation Option is getting into Manuel when I open Excel

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have an excel Macro in the form of an XLAM file. Whenever I open without my XLAM file, the Calculation Option is Automatic. But when I open with XLAM file, the Calculation Option in the Formula tab of the Ribbon Interface is Manual. Just as shown in this image. 
[image]

How to I make it come to Automatic by default?

In my entire macro, I have never used

```
Application.Calculation
```

and made it xlManual or xlAutomatic , but still the issue appears.

I tried to put

```
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

in

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
```

as shown in the below image
[image]

But if I do that and then close and reopen Excel, this error appears. 
[image]
Which forces me to remove code in above image.

How can I solve this problem? Kindly help me.

Thanks
Jeevan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you saved the add-in when calculation was set to manual. You need to resave it while calculation is set to automatic.

Comment: How do I do that, My XLAM is there in C:\Users\jrex\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns directory. When I open excel that macro automatically gets enabled. When I save it it doesn't show option to save as XLAM after changing it to automatic.

Comment: Hi, I opened my file, unlocked the code (Ctrl+Alt+F11 and then gave password), then changed it Calculation Option to Automatic, saved as XLAM. But this is getting saved as a new XLAM without the old code. Also when I reopen Calculation option is Manuel. How do I save in same XMAL by making it to automatic?

Comment: Change calculation to Automatic. Then in the VBE, with your add-in installed (don't open it separately), just type `Workbooks("your addin.xlam").Save` and press Enter. Then close and reopen Excel.